# New to Grok Filter and need help to convert different log formats of App logs to grok pattern

Tags: logstash-grok, grok

I am new to Grok, I have below app logs with different log format i.e fields are interchanged in App logs. need some common grok pattern to pick all fields. I tried with below pattern and got stuck with below line.

Grok Pattern tried is

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\s+%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}\s+\-\s+hash=%{NUMBER:hash:int}\s+threadid=%{NUMBER:threadid:int}\s+threads=%{NUMBER:threads:int}\s+\*\.\*\.\*\.\*\s+method=%{WORD:method}\s+|(loginname=%{USER:loginname})|\&|(request=%{WORD:request})|\&%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

Got stuck on the below line, because field location are interchanged. want below fields to be fetched based on field matching, it has special character "&" and "=".

```
loginname=foo&apiversion=1.7&request=result&opid=951&sessionid=o0xRRDoYqbCRzGWet9Nmrya8TABlc1mh043tXEc9abp18QQmkTM8EvmJQD2VncZq&playerip=*.*.*.*&type=&transactionid=59171154861&accountid=9024743&gpid=100&gpgameid=bonanza&wonamount=2.22&gamestatus=pending&currency=EUR&gamedetails=&device=desktop&roundid=24933725742 latency=114  cputime=9571 size=87 rc=0 balance=110.97000 realbalance=110.97 bonusbalance=0 currency=eur walletlatency=110
```

App log is

```
2023-07-10 09:10:23,252 INFO - hash=681253165 threadid=474927 threads=18 *.*.*.* method=GET loginname=foo&apiversion=1.7&request=result&opid=951&sessionid=o0xRRDoYqbCRzGWet9Nmrya8TABlc1mh043tXEc9abp18QQmkTM8EvmJQD2VncZq&playerip=*.*.*.*&type=&transactionid=59171154861&accountid=9024743&gpid=100&gpgameid=bonanza&wonamount=2.22&gamestatus=pending&currency=EUR&gamedetails=&device=desktop&roundid=24933725742 latency=114  cputime=9571 size=87 rc=0 balance=110.97000 realbalance=110.97 bonusbalance=0 currency=eur walletlatency=110
2023-07-10 09:10:23,261 INFO - hash=1518212572 threadid=474839 threads=18 *.*.*.* method=GET loginname=foo&apiversion=1.7&request=wager&opid=962&sessionid=R3w2OTIxOTUwMXw4Mi4xMzIuMTg2LjE2MnxRUm93ZmpybmdzVnlnNHVKWk5leExZYXJLZFNTLXBORlBhd2toemI4YWtrMU1lV1hiYUUyRVJ6bHd6RlJGNktUM2hkQnZmMlJOYjhJdHcyS2VpYkcteXpNamZ5ZkRyaGdrclRzWGRSa0w2eFgwclM2Z0pmNklzNy1iRnh3M2hMOQ%3D%3D&playerip=*.*.*.*&type=&transactionid=59171155358&accountid=69219501&gpid=100&gpgameid=monopolyonthemoneydeluxe94&currency=GBP&device=mobile&roundid=24933726913&betamount=0.30 latency=122  cputime=30139 size=124 rc=0 realmoneybet=0.30 bonusmoneybet=0 balance=43.74000 realbalance=43.740 bonusbalance=0.000 currency=gbp walletlatency=117
2023-07-10 09:10:23,274 INFO - hash=898374059 threadid=474928 threads=18 *.*.*.* method=GET loginname=blueprint&apiversion=1.5&gpid=117&device=mobile&request=result&opid=113&sessionid=MrGreenIE%3ade5ff948a460ecb2772b0fc7efab0e3f_114363937&currency=EUR&gpgameid=BP_EyeOfHorusGoldenTabletMegaways93&accountid=114363937&wonamount=0&transactionid=11114622801238117&roundid=14622800538117&gamestatus=completed&playerip=*.*.*.* latency=483  cputime=8881 size=50 rc=0 balance=170.90 currency=eur walletlatency=478
2023-07-10 09:10:23,293 INFO - hash=1476329565 threadid=474912 threads=18 *.*.*.* method=GET loginname=foo&apiversion=1.7&request=wager&opid=962&sessionid=R3w4MTQyNTU3NHwxMDkuMTQ0LjMxLjYxfEpaRzYtUFpoQVJRSlA4dmw0QkpFRHFLMm5lUmwtWlM5Vk8wdzZqc0RPbXEtcW5WLWtmTlVEMlUtSmlXbzJlRzkzaGRCdmYyUk5iOEl0dzJLZWliRy15ek1qZnlmRHJoZ2tyVHNYZFJrTDZ5UEVsZ3hpc1R4d3JfM0RXbDYwVVIy&playerip=*.*.*.*&type=&transactionid=59171155360&accountid=81425574&gpid=100&gpgameid=reelemintournamentfishing94&currency=GBP&device=mobile&roundid=24933726914&betamount=0.20 latency=125  cputime=16373 size=124 rc=0 realmoneybet=0.20 bonusmoneybet=0 balance=15.22000 realbalance=15.220 bonusbalance=0.000 currency=gbp walletlatency=120
2023-07-10 09:10:23,333 INFO - hash=1217134617 threadid=474935 threads=18 *.*.*.* method=GET loginname=foo&apiversion=1.7&request=wager&opid=1612&sessionid=AGwHOfmcCnUAAAABLD8pDpPL0Wh9MsiunSggRhM3rr4&playerip=*.*.*.*&type=&transactionid=59171154866&accountid=121239964&gpid=100&gpgameid=monopolymegaways96&currency=GBP&device=mobile&roundid=24933725886&betamount=0.20 latency=121  cputime=6428 size=123 rc=0 realmoneybet=0.20 bonusmoneybet=0.00 balance=8.29000 realbalance=8.29 bonusbalance=0.00 currency=gbp walletlatency=115
```